# PFObject subclass pointer assignment without prefetching the related PFObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfobject, pfsubclassing

I'm using PFObject subclassing, say:

```
@interface CarObject : PFObject <PFSubclassing>
@property (nonatomic, strong) BrandObject *brand;
@end
```

and

```
@interface  BrandObject : PFObject <PFSubclassing>
@end
```

How can I create CarObject with a reference to respective BrandObject without creating or fetching the BrandObject if I know BrandObject.objectId string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an empty placeholder object with a specified I'd by using [`objectWithoutDataWithClassName:objectId:`](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/objectWithoutDataWithClassName:objectId:).

Comment: I will accept after 2 min:) Could you please add how to perform this when initializing the CarObject with NSDictionary containing the BrandObject.objectId?

Comment: You can add your own convenience method which takes that parameter and returns the instance